# R: How can I transfer values from one data frame to another data frame depending on certain circumstances?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Is there a way in R to transfer values from one data frame to a second data frame if certain conditions are met? Specifically, I am concerned with the following problem:

I have values for different people in data frame 1 (columns: name, year of birth, place of birth in ISO-3) and the polity scores for different countries in data frame 2 (columns: country in ISO-3, year, score). I would now like to add the corresponding polity scores from data frame 2 to data frame 1 as a new column depending on country and year. Can I automate this via R?

**Data frame 1**

| Name | Country of Birth | Year of Birth | Polity Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | USA | 2018 | *Score from data frame 2* |
| Name 2 | DNK | 1995 | *Score from data frame 2* |

**Data frame 2**

| Country | Year | Polity Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2018 | 10 |
| DNK | 1995 | 10 |

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us your data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the 2 tables up, there are lots of methods and packages to do this but I am always a fan of the tidyverse, in this case `dplyr` [joins](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html).

Without seeing your table specifics it will look something like this.

```
df_joined <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Country of Birth" = "Country", "Year of Birth" = "Year")
```

Comment: The problem is that in data frame 2 (polity scores) there are thousands of values (for all countries of the world over a period of more than 100 years). However, I only want to transfer the corresponding polity score for the rows in data frame 1 (people).

Comment: Have a quick read about join types (left, inner, outer), the link above goes into it a little but in this case a left join will take the items from df1 and only bring in the data for the corresponding country and year.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I just tried it in R and it works. Thanks for your quick help! I wish you only the best!

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
df_joined <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c("Country of Birth", "Year of Birth"),
       by.y = c("Country", "Year"), all.x = TRUE)
```